# como puedo mover la ruta trazada en mapkit swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

lo que pasa que si me marca la ruta y todo, pero si me muevo ya sea hacia la dirección, o en contra, la ruta trazada sigue ahi, y yo quiero que si camino desaparezca la ruta junto conmigo, o vuelva a aparecer.
como puedo lograr eso?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

anexo código:

let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
        directions.calculate(completionHandler: {
            response, error in
            guard let response = response else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("algo salio mal(error)")
                }
                return
            }

```
        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.mapkitView.add(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)
        let minutos = Int(route.expectedTravelTime / 60.0)

        print("distancia segun yo jeje->\(minutos)")
        let rekt = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.mapkitView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rekt), animated: true)
    })

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitud, longitud)
    annotation.title = nombre
    annotation.subtitle = "Aqui mero quieres llegar"
    mapkitView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.5607843399, alpha: 1)
    renderer.lineWidth = 5.0

    return renderer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar la ruta que has puesto, puedes usar

```
self.mapView.removeOverlays(self.mapView.overlays)
```

y después la vuelves a pintar con los nuevos datos